# Long lived access token photo posting bug

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the long lived `access_token` (2 months) for posting content on a Facebook fan page.

So I use the following for posting text (with success):

```
$params = array(
                'access_token' => 'token',
                'message'=> ":-) <3",
                'image' => '@' . $image['file']
);

$post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed','post',$params);
```

And this code for posting photos in a album

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$image['file'] = 'images/rezultate/facebook_photo_170439606380900.jpg';
$args = array( 'access_token' => 'token', 'message' => ':-) <3', 'no_story' => 0);
$args['image'] = '@' . $image['file'];
$target_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/356048711158011/photos";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$target_url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

The problem is: why with **long lived access token I cannot post photos**? Only text, but if I use **2 hours (short-lived) access token I can post photos**.

Comment: What error message are you receeiving? Do other requests work?

Comment: No error .... long acces only post text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the token of the page that you have received from this extended_user_token.
Follow the steps from start:

1. Go to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)
2. Select you App on the upper-rightmost Application menu
3. Get the access token(short-term token).
4. Generate the long-term access token(2 months) from above token  using:

   ```
    graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID& client_secret=APP_SECRET& grant_type=fb_exchange_token& fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
   ```
5. Now use **this** access token and call "/me/accounts"
6. In the result, copy the access token corresponding to your page
7. Check this token's validity through [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). This token for page will never expire.

Use this token with your code.